# How to hide/disable 'My Mac (Designed for iPad)' Build Target - Xcode 13

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, unity-game-engine

Recently I moved to using an M1 Mac Mini as a build machine for Unity IOS projects through Xcode.

Often I would use the Unity option to 'Build and Run' which would auto open Xcode and build the app - often this would select the first available device target. I can always select the iPhone to build to but it always reverts back to 'My Mac' build target when Xcode opens the project again despite the phone staying connected via USB.

This M1 Mac Mini seems to have 'My Mac (Designed for iPad)' as a build target for iPhone/iPad only apps (not mac build target) and Xcode automatically chooses to build for that target rather than the connected iPhone when Unity exports the build.

Is there a way to exclude that My Mac build target in Xcode or in the Xcode project? I only want to test on device and we are exporting as Device SDK not Simulator SDK for this reason.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can hide it by setting this option to No
[image]

After that, choose "Append" instead of "Replace" every time you "Build and Run" your Unity project. If you choose "Replace", Unity will erase Xcode settings and you will need to set it again.

Answer (score 2):

From this forum post on [Unity Forum post](https://forum.unity.com/threads/how-to-hide-disable-my-mac-designed-for-ipad-build-target-xcode-13-on-m1-mac.1188952/) I made is an easy editor script fix

```
    #if UNITY_IOS
 
using System;
using System.IO;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEditor.Callbacks;
using UnityEditor.iOS.Xcode;
using UnityEngine;
 
public class iOSPostProccessorBuild
{
    [PostProcessBuild(2000)]
    public static void OnPostProcessBuild(BuildTarget target, string path)
    {
        Debug.Log("iOSBuildPostProcess is now postprocessing iOS Project");
 
        var projectPath = PBXProject.GetPBXProjectPath(path);
 
        var project = new PBXProject();
        project.ReadFromFile(projectPath);
 
        var targetGuid = project.GetUnityMainTargetGuid();
 
        project.SetBuildProperty(targetGuid, "SUPPORTS_MAC_DESIGNED_FOR_IPHONE_IPAD", "NO");
 
        try
        {
            var projectInString = File.ReadAllText(projectPath);
            projectInString = projectInString.Replace("SUPPORTS_MAC_DESIGNED_FOR_IPHONE_IPAD = YES;",
                $"SUPPORTS_MAC_DESIGNED_FOR_IPHONE_IPAD = NO;");
            File.WriteAllText(projectPath, projectInString);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.LogException(e);
        }
 
        project.WriteToFile(projectPath);
    }
}
 
#endif
```

Answer (score -2):

Try to connect your device to Xcode via USB to see if it detects your device, once Xcode recognizes your device select it and build your project on that device of yours.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question, I can switch to build target iPhone using the build device in Xcode, however I have to do that every time I click build & run in Unity as Xcode decides that despite the phone device (which is still connected and was the last device the app was built and deployed to) is not the default build target anymore. It always switched back to 'My Mac (Designed for iPad)' when Xcode opens the project.

Comment: Being able to hide/disable the My Mac target would solve this issue entirely, especially as I can be doing multiple builds throughout the work day where Xcode keeps trying to build to the Mac not the iPhone.

Comment: I am encountering exactly the same problem. That is so annoying! Have you found a solution yet? @ROBYER1